# Paypal button submit multiple items at once with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I have an angularJS application with a custom `cart`, I am trying to use paypal to allow the user to checkout their entire `cart` at one time.

HTML

```
<main ng-controller="CheckoutCtrl" class="prototype-paypal">
  <h2 class="checkout-header">Checkout</h2>

  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">

    <div ng-repeat="item in custCart">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{$index}}" value="{{item.name}}" >
      <input ng-repeat="size in item.sizes track by $index" type="hidden" name="amount_{{$index}}"
               value="{{size.price}}">
    </div>

    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" 
           alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
  </form>

</main>
```

I think I am using `$index` wrong, here is my data:

```
$scope.custCart = [];    

$scope.templateItems = [
{
  name: 'First Item',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
  src: 'http://placehold.it/150x150.gif',
  type: 'Template',
  sizes: [
    {
      size: "Small",
      price: 3.99,
      text: "size of item sm more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Medium",
      price: 5.99,
      text: "size of item md more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Large",
      price: 7.99,
      text: "size of item lg more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "X-Large",
      price: 8.99,
      text: "size of item xl",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "XX-Large",
      price: 10.99,
      text: "size of item xxl",
      numOrders: 0,
    }
    ]
},
{
  name: 'Second Item',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
  src: 'http://placehold.it/150x150.gif',
  type: 'Template',
  sizes: [
    {
      size: "Small",
      price: 3.99,
      text: "size of item sm ",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Medium",
      price: 5.99,
      text: "size of item md more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Large",
      price: 7.99,
      text: "size of item lg more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    }
    ],
},
{
  name: 'Third Item',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
  src: 'http://placehold.it/150x150.gif',
  type: 'Template',
  sizes: [
    {
      size: "Small",
      price: 3.99,
      text: "size of item sm ",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Medium",
      price: 5.99,
      text: "size of item md more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Large",
      price: 7.99,
      text: "size of item lg more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    }
    ],
},
{
  name: 'Fourth Item',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
  src: 'http://placehold.it/150x150.gif',
  type: 'Template',
  sizes: [
    {
      size: "Small",
      price: 3.99,
      text: "size of item sm ",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Medium",
      price: 5.99,
      text: "size of item md more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    },
    {
      size: "Large",
      price: 7.99,
      text: "size of item lg more details more",
      numOrders: 0,
    }
    ],
}
];
```

The problem is that my `ng-repeat` loops are for some reason not displaying the first item in `custCart`

Comment: I'd be surprised if you were getting anything at all.  AngularJS ignores hidden inputs.

Comment: oh, well I am getting 1 item with the price and name.. but it's just not repeating through .. how can I fix u think?

Comment: ah... you're not having a problem with binding, it's the repeat that's the issue?

Comment: What does custCart look like?  In the example above, it's an empty array and there's no hint as to how it's populated.

Comment: yes, actually I am seeing all the items except for the first item is not appearing

Comment: can test it here now: http://cisweb.ufv.ca/~300105626/ForeverLeather/#/belts

Comment: The problem isn't your ng-repeat.  It's somewhere in your cart code.  If you right-click and inspect the form after you click checkout, you can see that it's correctly creating 1 or more divs corresponding to each item in your cart.  However, it's repeating all of the sizes for the the entire item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82113/discussion-between-alex-di-vito-and-jme11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the ng-repeat.  It is correct based on your data structure.  I would change the approach to the way you're adding data to your cart.  Presently, you're pushing all of the "item" sizes to the cart regardless if the user selects that particular size of item or not and you're just using ng-class to hide the sizes that have a quantity of 0.  That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

That said, you can use filter in your view to filter out the items with a quantity of 0.  The difference between what you're doing now which is just using CSS to hide those values, and using the filter is that the filter won't actually generate any DOM elements for any of the values that don't match the filter.

So you could do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
    return function(item){
      return item[prop] > val;
    }
}
```

Then in your repeat:

```
ng-repeat="size in item.sizes | filter: greaterThan('numOrders', 0) track by $index"
```

Alternatively, you can use ngIf, which will also not render the DOM elements such as:

```
<input ng-repeat="size in item.sizes track by $index" ng-if="size.numOrders <= 0" type="hidden" name="amount_{{$index}}" value="{{size.price}}">
```

Still, I highly recommend that you take a look at how you might optimize your cart functionality.  There is a very good book called [Pro AngularJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HX4PJ9I).  I seem to recall that the main example used the book goes step by step through creating an online shop.  You might want to get it just for the example code.  It would definitely help you streamline what you've got, set up a service for the cart and use custom directives for example for the cart dropdown.

Comment: You're right in the way that I am doing this.. This is my first time doing transactions online and i'm just trying to figure it out on my own so I definitely appreciate this and I will look at this book you mentioned.. would it be ok if i message you if I have more issues?

Comment: Sure. I actually integrated an online ticketing system with PayPal last year, so I know how daunting it can be at times.  I wish you much luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" 
           alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
```

Replace it with :

```
<input type="submit" style="background:url(http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif); width:100px; height:100px;" name="Submit" 
           alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
```